# Excel 2016 Countf function using multiple criterion help needed

Tags: excel, function, countif

I am trying to figure out how to take a worksheet and break out some information using `countif` functions and/or be able to show it in a pivot table functions.

The problem I am having is that some of the data in one of the cells has more than one piece of information.  This is a sample:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦═══════╦══════════════════╗
║ Claim ║    Date    ║ Model ║ Fail Description ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬═══════╬══════════════════╣
║       ║            ║       ║                  ║
║     1 ║ 1/1/2017   ║ T430  ║ KB, MOBO         ║
║     2 ║ 1/5/2017   ║ t450  ║ KB, MOBO         ║
║     3 ║ 1/6/2017   ║ T440  ║ HDD, MOBO        ║
║     4 ║ 1/7/2017   ║  CTO  ║ HDD              ║
║     5 ║ 1/8/2017   ║ T430  ║ KB               ║
║     6 ║ 1/9/2017   ║ t450  ║ KB               ║
║     7 ║ 1/10/2017  ║ T440  ║ LID              ║
║     8 ║ 1/10/2017  ║  CTO  ║ LID, KB          ║
║     9 ║ 1/10/2017  ║ T430  ║ HDD, MOBO        ║
║    10 ║ 1/7/2017   ║ t450  ║ KB, MOBO         ║
║    11 ║ 1/7/2017   ║ T440  ║ KB, MOBO         ║
║    12 ║ 1/7/2017   ║  CTO  ║ HDD, MOBO        ║
║    13 ║ 1/7/2017   ║ T430  ║ HDD              ║
║    14 ║ 1/7/2017   ║ t450  ║ KB               ║
║    15 ║ 1/5/2017   ║ T440  ║ KB               ║
║    16 ║ 1/5/2017   ║  CTO  ║ LID              ║
║    17 ║ 1/5/2017   ║ T430  ║ LID, KB          ║
║    18 ║ 1/5/2017   ║ t450  ║ HDD, MOBO        ║
║    19 ║ 1/5/2017   ║ T440  ║ KB, MOBO         ║
║    20 ║ 1/5/2017   ║  CTO  ║ KB, MOBO         ║
║    21 ║ 12/25/2017 ║ T430  ║ HDD, MOBO        ║
║    22 ║ 12/25/2017 ║ t450  ║ HDD              ║
║    23 ║ 12/25/2017 ║ T440  ║ KB               ║
║    24 ║ 12/25/2017 ║ T450  ║ KB               ║
║    25 ║ 12/25/2017 ║ T450  ║ LID              ║
║    26 ║ 12/25/2017 ║ T440  ║ LID, KB          ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩═══════╩══════════════════╝
```

As you can see the `Fail Description` sometimes has more than one value separated by a comma.   I would like to take a count of each type of fail based on model type of computer.  So a `countif (C2:C27, "*450")` and also `countif (D2:D27, "*MOBO*")`  Asking how many 450's needed a Motherboard.  I have tried it several different ways and either end up with a #Value or 0 error.   Does anyone have any suggestions?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmmm...

I hope I understand your question correctly

```
=COUNTIFS($C:$C,"*450*",$D:$D,"*MOBO*")
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was asking, In Fact I had tried that particular string before and it did not work, however, typing it again as you suggested, it worked exactly as I want! Perhaps it was my order.  Does it matter what Order I ask for the information in?      It's going to be tedious but I have to do this for each Model and Type of Part.  Thank you very much!   Also, any suggestions on making the Pivot Table work with this type of information?